# The pointer to memory location to the object has been deleted in program but still provides the correct answer and not garbage value

Tags: c++, class, new-operator, delete-operator

The pointer *sbi memory is freed using the delete operator but still the code executes correctly without providing garbage value.  is the constructor re-initializing or is the a fault in code/

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class bank
{
private:
    int balance;
public:
    bank();
    void dep(int x);
    void with();
    ~bank();
};
int main()
{
    bank *sbi;
    sbi = new bank;
    sbi->dep(50000);
    delete sbi;   /// problem is in this section of code 
    sbi->with();
    return 0;
}

bank :: bank()
{
    balance=0;
}

void bank::dep(int x)
{
    balance=x;
}

void bank::with()
{
    cout<<balance<<endl;
}

bank::~bank()
{
    cout<<"destroy"<<endl;
}
```

Comment: Memory doesn't magically cease to exist or become unavailable or change its contents. Dereferencing a pointer to memory you don't own leads to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Once you've free'd memory (through `free` or `delete` or `delete[]`) you should no longer attempt to dereference the pointer (unless you reassign it to point to some valid memory).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Freeing a memory location does not automatically overwrite it with garbage. By coincidence, that value stored in balance is still the same.

Comment: Note also, it's not guaranteed to be or remain the same. As soon as the memory location is re-allocated and re-written the value will change and so cannot be relied upon as accessing it is undefined behaviour and a source of many many hard to find software bugs in the past.